# How to make a loginFilter of a server in Angular?

Tags: angular, servlets, jersey

I have a servlet project in front of each application that runs a filter that checks whether there is a session user. If it is not directed to the login page.
The problem: Now I want to convert the html pages in servlet to SPA (angular) and I do not even know where to start.

**the loginservlet :**

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public static final String KEY_FACAED = "facaed";

    private static final String PARAM_LOGIN_TYPE = "loginType";
    private static final String PARAM_PASSWORD = "password";
    private static final String PARAM_USER_NAME = "userName";

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        req.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/login.html").forward(req, resp);

    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // For userName -> the inserted user name.
        String userName = req.getParameter(PARAM_USER_NAME);
        // For password --> the inserted password.
        String password = req.getParameter(PARAM_PASSWORD);
        // loginType --> The login type , one of : ADMIN, COMPANY, CUSTOMER.
        String type = req.getParameter(PARAM_LOGIN_TYPE);
        LoginType loginType = LoginType.valueOf(type);
        //Generates a new session:
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
        //Try to login:
        try {
            AbsFacaed facaed = CouponSystem.getInstance().login(userName, password, loginType);
            String pathURI;
            switch (loginType) {
                case ADMIN:
                    pathURI = "WEB-INF/admin.html";
                    break;
                case COMPANY:
                    pathURI = "WEB-INF/company.html";
                    break;
                default:/* CUSTOMER */
                    pathURI = "WEB-INF/customer.html";
                    break;
            }

            req.getRequestDispatcher(pathURI).forward(req, resp);
            session.setAttribute(KEY_FACAED, facaed);

        } catch (InvalidLoginException | SystemMalfunctionException e) {
            resp.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/login");
        }
    }
}
```

This the html login page that i build in eclips:

```
<form action="login" method="post">

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login</legend>
        User name:<br> <input type="text" name="userName"><br>
        Password:<br> <input type="password" name="password">
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="radiogroup">
        <legend>Select login type</legend>
        <ul class="radio">
            <li><input type="radio" name="loginType" id="i1" value="ADMIN">
                <label for="i1"> Administrator</label></li>
            <li><input type="radio" name="loginType" id="i2"
                value="COMPANY"> <label for="i2"> Company</label></li>
            <li><input type="radio" name="loginType" id="i3"
                value="CUSTOMER"> <label for="i3"> Customer</label></li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

I thought of doing this in Angular:

html:

```
<form action="login" method="post">

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Login</legend>
    User name:<br> <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myService.userName" name="userName"><br>
    Password:<br> <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="myService.password" name="password">
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="radiogroup">
    <legend>Select login type</legend>
    <ul class="radio">
      <li><input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="myService.loginType" id="i1" value="ADMIN" name="loginType">
        <label for="i1"> Administrator</label></li>
      <li><input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="myService.loginType" id="i2" value="COMPANY" name="loginType" >
         <label for="i2"> Company</label></li>
      <li><input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="myService.loginType" id="i3" value="CUSTOMER" name="loginType"> 
        <label for="i3"> Customer</label></li>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" (onclick)="myService.doLogin()">

</form>
```

ts(The service) :

```
export class MainServiceService {


  private password:string;
  private userName:string;
  private loginType:string;

  constructor(private myHttpClient:HttpClient) { 

  }

  public doLogin(){
   let user:any = {
      userName: this.userName,
      password: this.password,
      loginType: this.loginType
    };
    this.myHttpClient.get<any>("http://localhost:8080/CouponSystemJersey/login?password="+this.password+"&loginType="+this.loginType+"&userName="+this.userName).subscribe(
       (res)=>{},
       (err)=>{console.log}
    )
  }
}
```

The page does not respond, there is a mistake I do not know where and how to solve it.
Of course I run everything on an insecure page to override the CROS policy.
I would be happy to have any idea or even recommendations for a course in Udemy that explains how to do it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should make a http post request on submit: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: But if the login requests are successful it does getRequestDispatcher to the HTML page written in the eclipse.
What will happen?
I'll add the part of the login

Comment: I updated changes